# ActiveRecord DeleteRestrictionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Page.rb

```
has_many :comments, :dependent => :restrict
```

This validation raises

```
PagesController# (ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError) "Cannot delete record because of `dependent comments"`
```

Is there a way to show it like a flash message or with other validation messages.?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use begin/rescue to catch that exception and then add the error message to the base errors for page...  my syntax is off, but something like...

```
begin
  @page.destroy
rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
  @page.errors.add(:base, e)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also deal with it in application controller, if you don't want to put begin rescue blocks in many of your controllers.

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError do |exception|
  redirect_to(:back, :alert => exception.message)
end
```

It will redirect to the page or resource from which the request came and will show an alert message.